# ADF-Passing values from the selected row to another page when click Details button

Tags: oracle-adf

I am new to ADF, I want to display the details of the selected row when click on detail button and in the same time the page I want to display the details must retrieve the data based on bind variables (RequstNo and DeptId). So how I can pass these values from the selected row to details page.

please advise

Comment: This question shows no research effort. It is very unclear also. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How Do I Ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pageflowscope variables to pass values between pages.
An example here: https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/passing-value-between-pages-to-filter-a-view-object

Comment: Thank you, but the example must be with same view object, and what I have is two different view objects "orders_to_confirmVO" and "request_detaisVO", and I want to pass the values based on the following select (SELECT   column1,column 2.....     
FROM  table 1, table 2 where (some conditions) 
AND DEPT_NO =:pDeptNo AND RQ_NO =:pRqNo)

Comment: Did you watch the video? It shows how to do it with two separate VOs. Setting the bind parameter binding to the pageflowscope variable - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eyzBiIf5MM

Comment: thank you so much, that is what I really need, but I am getting the following exception (oracle.jbo.ConfigException: JBO-29114 ADFContext is not setup to process messages for this exception. Use the exception stack trace and error code to investigate the root cause of this exception. Root cause error code is JBO-33005. Error message parameters are {0=TestAMLocal}
 at oracle.jbo.client.Configuration.loadConfiguration(Configuration.java:610)

)

Answer (score 0):

Create View link between your view object.and add partial trigger of detail table to header table.

Comment: Thank you, but would you please provide me an example?

Comment: also to clarify more, this is two different pages page one has the table and page two is the form that I want to display based on the selected row and based on the following query: (SELECT column1,column 2..... FROM table 1, table 2 where (some conditions) AND DEPT_NO =:pDeptNo AND RQ_NO =:pRqNo)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters between two view objects using pageflowScope variables or by simply creating parent child relationship(view link) between them.
Using different pageFlowScope variable collect the required parameters then
programmatically set the bind variables of the VO and execute the query.
Also, set the bind variables property from untrusted to trusted.